# how can i make my back button work similar to device back button android

Tags: android

I have implemented presently back button like below

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/back"
                style="@style/NavButtons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:onClick="finishActivity"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
```

and in code i am doing

```
public void finishActivity(View v) {
        finish();
    }
```

But the back button i have implemented doesnt work similar to device back button. what i should make my back button implementation work similar to device back button?

Thanks:)

Comment: What do you mean by `doesnt work similar to device back button`?

Comment: suppose i have traveresed some 5 screens from home page and if i press the back button which i have implemented it will travel all the 5 screens. but device back button take me to home page with just 3 presses.

Comment: It should be working fine, please explain what is going wrong. You are calling **finish()**, which is what exactly is called if the back button is pressed, in the **onBackPressed()** method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
super.onbackpressed();
```

if you want to do the same as the devices back button, just programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void finishActivity(View v) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer android  developer site for activity stack

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html